# Google Sheets value function

Tags: google-sheets

Hi First off I am a beginner with Google Sheets, and I am tasked with this issue.

I'd like to create a sheet (sheet 3) that can take values from sheet 2 but have a different value in sheet 3.

Here is my idea using the values in mind;

- I want the "present" value from sheet 2 to equal "0" value in sheet 3
- I want the "less than 10mins" value from sheet 2 to equal "+1" value in sheet 3
- I want the "more than 10mins" value from sheet 2 to equal "+2" value in sheet 3
- I want the  "unexcused" value from sheet 2 to equal "+5" value in sheet 3
- I want the "excused" value from sheet 2 to equal "0" value in sheet 3

There are multiple columns that account for single individuals.

So if person A, had the value "unexcused" in sheet 2 on 03/07/19, I want person A to have +5 added to his total from before, maybe from previous weeks his total was 2, so after the value "unexcused" was added on 03/07/19, he would now have 7 for his up to date total. I'd also like to be able to manually add or subtract a number from the data but not alter the function if possible.

I apologize if I have done a poor job of explaining, or have omitted some details, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(Sheet2!A1="present",0,)

=IF(Sheet2!A1="less than 10mins","+1",)

=IF(Sheet2!A1="more than 10mins","+2",)

=IF(Sheet2!A1="unexcused","+5",)

=IF(Sheet2!A1="excused",0,)
```